# Page renders for a second and then disappears - Vue JS

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm new to using Vue and am trying to build a simple search feature that takes an input query and returns all users that match the query.

I'm attempting to do this by following along to a [video demonstration](https://www.livecoding.tv/ozankurt/videos/lN45N-instant-search-vuejs-laravel-5-2) of it.

I have no clue where I am going wrong as there is no error in my console, however I am currently facing an issue where the page loads and I can see the content for a second and then it flashes white and the page goes blank.

The code for the page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta id="X-CSRF-TOKEN" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="searchPage">

            <h1>Real Time Search</h1>

            <form class="form-horizontal" v-on="submit: false">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Search:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="query" v-on="keyup: search">
                </div>
            </form>

            <pre>@{{ $data | json }}</pre>

        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And my `app.js` script looks like this:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.getElementById('X-CSRF-TOKEN').getAttribute('content');

new Vue({

    el: '#searchPage',
    data: {

        query: '',
        users: [],

    },
    methods: {
        search: function() {
            this.$http.post('/', { query: this.query } ).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(response) {
                    // error callback
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong? Or what is causing this?

Comment: I just want to share a reminder that the production version of Vue does not print warnings to the console. You want to use the development version of Vue to see the warnings to be able to troubleshoot this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things here. Firstly, you are using Vue 2.0. In vue 2.0 the `v-on="submit:...";` syntax is deprecated (in fact it looks like this syntax is from 0.12). If you want to stop the form submitting, you now need to add `v-on:submit.prevent`:

```
<!--This will stop the form from submitting -->
<form class="form-horizontal" v-on:submit.prevent>
```

You have a similar issue for `v-on="keyup: search"` which should be `v-on:keyup="search"`

```
<!-- Call the search method on keyup -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="query" v-on:keyup="search">
```

It's worth taking a look at the docs at: https://vuejs.org/guide/ to get familiar with the basic 2.0 syntax.

Comment: And just like that it's working! Thanks mate, wish I'd thought to check that!

Comment: Good luck with Vue, it's great once you get past the initial frustrations of the learning phase.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a different, much simpler answer.  I've just spent a couple of hours trying to solve the same symptoms.  It turns out my problem was this:

[image]

Yup, I'd put "=" not "==" on the second condition.  Now in VB you'd never have had that problem ...

Quite why this stops the whole page appearing without any errors in the console, I'm not sure, but I have to say in general I'm loving Vue JS (for the first time I can actually write client applications productively).